# C# Method performance significantly decreases because of constructor parameter name mismatch

Tags: c#, performance, naming, cil

I've created a program that solves sudoku puzzles using a backtracking algorithm. To do this I've created a class called Tile with a constructor that takes a boolean flag signifying if the tile is open for user input or not.

```
/// <summary>
/// Represents a single tile in a sudoku board
/// </summary>
public class Tile
{
    public int Row { get; set; }

    public int Column { get; set; }

    public int Box { get; set; }

    public int Value { get; set; }

    public bool ReadOnly { get; private set; }

    public Tile(bool @readonly = false)
    {
        this.ReadOnly = @readonly;
    }
}
```

Passing in the following sudoku board takes 0.03 seconds to solve

```
                { 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 8, 0, 9, 0 },
                { 0, 0, 3, 6, 9, 0, 0, 0, 5 },
                { 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 4, 0, 3, 0 },

                { 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0 },
                { 0, 0, 8, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 0 },
                { 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0 },

                { 0, 1, 0, 8, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0 },
                { 4, 0, 0, 0, 6, 1, 9, 0, 0 },
                { 0, 7, 0, 2, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0 },
```

But if I change the names of the Tile.ReadOnly property or constructor parameter so that they do not match (eg: prop 'ReadOnly' and param 'ro') then solving the same board takes 8.63 seconds!

What is going here? Why would the name of a variable have such a significant impact on the program? Does this have something to do with how this is translated from C# to CIL? I looked at the assembly for both and it looked like the following lines were the only different ones

```
public Tile(bool @readonly = false)
012E254A  in          al,dx
```

vs

```
public Tile(bool ro = false)
00822548  push        ebp  
00822549  mov         ebp,esp
```

Is there any significance to these difference?
Full source code [here](https://pastebin.com/4KTeS84Q).

Comment: Unable to reproduce, both execute in roughly the same time. How many times did you go back and forth between `ro` and `@readonly` to be able to reproduce this difference? The `Tile` constructor only runs 81 times (as expected), that should never cause an 8 second difference.

Comment: Looks fishy. What does [BenchmarkDotNet](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/) have to say about it? Distrust home-grown benchmarks by default.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis I was able to reproduce this 100% of the time. I've swapped between the two roughly 10 times each.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Regardless of the accuracy of using the Stopwatch, my computer will hang for ~8 seconds while this is run, compared to no hang when the variable names match.

Comment: Do you use Release builds, run it without Visual studio and have a warm-up run that is not measured? To make it simple you can copy/paste all code and ignore first measurement

Comment: @dlxeon Yeah, I've tried running it in release mode as well. No significant difference.

Comment: @CaptainGorilla: the accuracy of `Stopwatch` is not what concerns me, it's whatever else is throwing in those 8 seconds. BenchmarkDotNet auto-compensates for one-time differences due to JIT warmup, for starters, as well as other outliers. It can also directly compare timing and assembly differences between the code. For all we know it could be because one version triggers a virus scanner's heuristic checks due to a unique arrangement of bits. If it shows a difference, you'll have a better idea what the difference is; otherwise you know things are even more interesting than they appear.

Comment: @CaptainGorilla If that 8 seconds are 100% reproducible if you run your .exe file without visual studio, then you can use PerfView to capture all OS activity and figure out what exactly happens during that time, which process consume CPU, what is waiting, how much time does JIT compilation or GC takes. As Jeroen Mostert said that can be your anti-virus software or something else in system causing that impact

Comment: The IN instruction is not accurate, only privileged code can ever execute it.  The managed debugging engine in VS2015+ is very buggy and does not correctly restore breakpoints.  Use Tools > Options > Debugging > General and tick the "Use Managed Compatibility Mode" checkbox.  Doesn't explain anything, but at least you'd be a bit more likely to not get stuck on bad info and discover that Sudoko solving is NP-hard.

Answer (score 2):

That shouldn't influence at all in theory and I can't get notable difference either.

I think you are measuring it wrong. There should be warm-up cycle to ensure jit compilation is done. Also you need to benchmark only Release without debugger attached

**Update**: took version with "ro" name (x64 release built run without VS), done cycle with 100 executions and got 6.5 seconds execution time, mostly spent on string concatenation and TileIsValid

[image: CPU profiling]